# how to use "set environment variables" in blue ocean?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I don't know how to use 'set environment variables' in blue ocean.

The following are the details:

1. I add a step by the Blue Ocean UI
2. Click tab 'Set Environment Variable'

But i don't know how to use. I want to set a environment variable in a step, and use it in next step.Kindly help.

Comment: Can you provide some information about what you are trying to achieve here? Which variable are you trying to set? What will the environment variable be used for?

Comment: I want to use the value of Variable to decide how to restart the application after update codes.

Comment: example: if the value of Variable is 'restart_all', i will restart all application concurrently by use Pipeline.

Comment: So were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: yeah, thank you   @Curious

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem, just like following: 
  environment 
{
    TEST1 = readFile '123'
  
}

Comment: it's write in Jenkinsfile

Comment: This doesn't answer the question you posed. First of all this is editing the jenkinsfile, not using Blue Ocean. Second, setting environment variables is a different process to using the "Set Environment Variables" step.